# Inserting a value into a sequential series and then continuing the series

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Example data series has the sequence seeded with 1 as the initial value, and a step of 1.  There is a calculated value that needs to be inserted in the series, in this case it is 3.5

Desired output:

```
1
2
3
3.5
4
5
```

I am avoiding VBA, and I am avoiding sorts.  I am trying to do this with an IF formula.

So far I have tried the following A2 copied down:

```
=IF(A1+1<3.5,A1+1,IF(A1<>3.5,3.5,A1+1))
```

Seed value may be any real number.
Step value may be any real number.

Comment: `=IF(A1+1=4,3.5,FLOOR(A1+1,1))`  this works for seed and step of 1.  I'm not I'm not so sure about if the 3.5 changes or if step/seed change.

Comment: @xQbert just did a test.  Made B2 the step value and put .3 there...results, no so good.  But with the step of 1 it definitely works.

Comment: so the seed or step could be a fraction not just whole numbers (making sure we have the same definition of real number)?  (any number on number line)

Comment: Yes, fraction or decimal.  I am currently working on a break point check if the two previous cells are less then use the value...still not sure how to keep it counting.  Right now I am working with (row()-row(a1))*step but I do not have it working yet

Comment: figured it out.  UGLY in my actual case, but got it working  I will post simplified answer shortly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one formula:

```
=IF(AND(A1<$D$2,A1+$D$1>$D$2),$D$2,IF(A1<>$D$2,A1+$D$1,((QUOTIENT(A1-$A$1,$D$1)+1)*$D$1)+$A$1))
```

First we test whether the next step will pass the seed/inserted value and if so we insert the value.

IF not then we test whether the cell above is the inserted value. If not then we just step normally.  If it is then we take the value in the cell above and subtract the start value in A1.

With this value we divide by the step and get the quotient or number of steps made till this point.

We then add one to the quotient effectively getting the next step and multiply the step value.  we then add back in the start value and get the next step.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: ok, terminology/nomenclature question.  When the term SEED is used, does that mean the first value in the series? or something that is planted in the series? or something else completely different?  FYI still wrapping my head around the formula.

Comment: @ForwardEd Sorry yes I copied the wrong one, I put the correct formula for A2.  When I use Seed it is the value that gets inserted.  In A1 is the beginning value.  Then the step.  So three constants.  Start value in A1, Step D1 and Seed or inserted value in D2.

Comment: Now that I got my head around the logic checks, I prefer answer over mine. Bonus points for being good for a horizontal and vertical series!